# Will ActiveMQ be supported in Spring XD as transport in future?

Tags: spring-xd

We are using ActiveMQ as our standard messaging platform. XD already supports ActiveMQ as JMS source. Messaging platform as transport helps handle the sink failures by putting the payload in the ERROR queue named after the transport. If it were Redis, the payload goes into a LIST. Queue is better way to process the failed messages using a batch job. Wondering if ActiveMQ will be supported as a transport in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-1928 and put it on the roadmap for a 1.1 M1 release which will be later in the year.  Rabbit as the broker supports the same error handling semantics you mention.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/XD-Distributed-Runtime#error-handling-message-delivery-failures

has more info on error handling for both Redis and Rabbit.

Rabbit is the preferred message bus to use ATM, we also support redis since it is a way to validate the messagebus abstraction and it is already 'there' since we use it to store analytics.

Thanks for the feedback.

Cheers,

Mark